# OneDrive configured and then removed. How do I restore Documents to it's original location?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

My mom accidently configured onedrive on her Windows 10 machine.
That moved her Documents folder from:

```
c:\Users\Mom\Documents
```

to

```
c:\Users\Mom\OneDrive\Documents
```

(and maybe created a symlink?)

I uninstalled OneDrive but that didn't restore the Documents location.
I deleted `c:\Users\Mom\Documents` but Windows won't let me move the Documents folder back to original location

Answer (score 3):

Right click *Documents* then *Properties*, *Location* tab, *Restore Default* button.

Answer (score 1):

If moving it back to original location with "Restore Default" doesn't work, reinstall Onedrive the same way as it was before. Then try restoring the location, and once that's successful uninstall Onedrive.

Comment: Didn't work. Says folder with that name already exists. But there is no such folder. I removed it after uninstalling OneDrive and then tried your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try to check the related registry.

Locate to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`, then find the "Personal" value. Make sure its data value is `C:\Users\Mom\Documents`.

More information, you may refer to "[Configuration of the My Documents folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/configuration-of-the-my-documents-folder-dfd9a90d-8f80-18d6-e7cc-f1566fc3b10b)".